# Why is stack getting overflowed in this code?

Tags: opengl

I wrote this function for filling closed loop, *pixvali* is declared globally to store the color value of the pixel where the first click will be done (inside the closed loop).

But the problem is that this recursion doesn't terminate when its first *fill(..,..)*get over, and it says stack is overflowed...

```
void fill(int x,int y)
{
    GLfloat pixval[3];
    glReadPixels(x,y,1,1,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,pixval);
    if(pixval[0]==pixvali[0] && pixval[1]==pixvali[1] && pixval[2]== pixvali[2])
    {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2i(x,y);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
        fill(x-1,y);
        fill(x+1,y);
        fill(x,y-1);
        fill(x,y+1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: And add the language to the tags. It might look like C but there are quite a lot languages looking like C :)

Comment: are the pixel values set anywhere?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me 'pixvali' is the colour that should be flood filled.

Comment: Mate, you gotta explain more what your code is doing, how are you calling this function? some context man ...

Comment: Don't worry, you definetely came to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement your own stack, don't use recursion for flood fill unless you are filling shapes with relatively small surface area in terms of pixels.

a typical implementation is:

```
Stack stack; 
stack.push(firstPoint);

while(!stack.isEmpty()){
   Point currentPoint= stack.pop();
   //do what ever you want to do here, namely paint.
   //boundary check ur surrounding points and push them in the stack if they are inbounds
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The stack overflows because you are using recursion, and the depth of the recursion is linear in the number of pixels in the shape you're filling.

It may also be that you are trying to fill the shape in the same color as it already is. That is, the current gl color is the same as pixvali. In that case, you'll get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of hard to tell from the question, but my guess would be that, you begin going in a loop of pixels.

For example, think that you have only 4 pixels that you need to color (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1).

You begin coloring (0,0). Then your recursion will enter (1,0) since(-1,0) doesn't need coloring. then (0,0) again since, it's the pixel that is (x-1, y) again and so on.

You need to add some way to mark pixels that have been colored already. But that's just a guess because you can't really see what's going on outside that functions.

Comment: The comparison between pixval and pixvali is supposedly that marker. I just hope he draws with the pixvali color as he is reading the current xy color in pixval...

Comment: Where does he compare then to the filled color? (i.e. you want to fill color x with color y, you need to check that color x is filled and nothing else, other wise you can just flood the whole screen)

Personally I'd look for a color some distance from x, but that's not the point really.

Comment: see my problem is coming like:
It draws a line from the clicked point till the boundry going in -x direction.. As my first recurtion is for -x;
 after the line gets drawn, it shows stack overflow..
think on this properly and then post any comment..

Comment: I think that you should read the answers that you were given and think on them.

Comment: @Abhay: Try a smaller area to fill. My guess is that the stack is really too small for the area you try to fill.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the implementation details, but if the 12 byte local array is allocated on the stack (3 floats a 4 bytes each), then you have 4 bytes each for the x and y parameters, and probably four bytes for the return address.  That gives at least 24 every time you recurse.  That means you only need a bit more than 40'000 calls to blow through 1MB of stack space, if there's nothing else on it, which won't be true.

To put that in perspective, 43'690 pixels is only about 10% of an 800x600 display.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the array was GLFloat, my brain just substituted three bytes for RGB.  Obviously that would make the stack requirements even worse per call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what pixels are you editing.

e.g. If you have an image from 0,0 to 10,10 and you edit 11,10 you will get outside of memory.

So you need to check if x,y is between the boundaries of the image.

```
x>=left&&x<=right&&y>=top&&y<=bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the algorithm looks good. I'm a bit worried about the "==" because they don't work well with float values. I suggest to use

```
abs(val1 - val2) < limit
```

instead (where `limit` is < 1 and > 0. Try 0.0001, for example).

To track down the bug, I suggest to add a `printf()` at the beginning of the function. When you see what the function tries to fill, that will help. Maybe it is stuck somewhere and calls itself again and again with the same coordinates?

Also, the stack may simple be too small for the area you try to fill. Try with a small area first, say a small rectangle only 4 by 3 pixels. Don't try to click it with the mouse but start with a known good point inside (just call fill() in your code).

Also printing the values for the color could help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you abusing OpenGL for this? What you do there is very unstable. For example the pixel read by glReadPixels will only correspond to the vertex position if a carefully chosen combination of projection and modelview matrix is used. Also every iteration of fill will do a full round trip. Just because you're using OpenGL it doesn't get magically fast.

If you want to flood fill some area in the framebuffer, readout the whole framebuffer, do the floodfill on that and push the result back to OpenGL. Also if some part of the framebuffer is occluded (by a window, or similar), those parts won't be

Now to understand why you end up in a infinite recursion. Consider this:

`fill(4, 4)` will call `fill(5, 4)` will call `fill(5, 5)` will call `fill(4, 5)` will call `fill(4, 4)` ***boom***

Now you've got that test there:

```
if( pixval[0] == pixvali[0] && 
    pixval[1] == pixvali[1] && 
    pixval[2] == pixvali[2] )
```

Note that this evaluates true if the to be set pixel already has the target color, again winding up in a endless recursion. You should test for *inequality*.

Last but not least: A picture may consists of millions of pixels easily. Usual stack sizes allow only for at most a few 1000 function nesting levels, so you'll have convert your tail recursion into a iteration.

TL;DR: Don't use OpenGL for this, operate on a local buffer, use proper iteration condition test and use iteration instead of recursion (or use a functional language, then the compiler will take care of that tail recursion).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill